# Getting all the cell values from table using table header using Webdriver

Tags: selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver, css-selectors

[image: Table contents]

Below is the HTML code for the tables:

**I need to extract values from table preceding with header as "Opportunities".** 
Could someone please suggest the best way forward as I can extract values fine if they belong to the same table but I need help when they are in two different table and i need to look for table opportunities and than extract data from the preceding table.

Comment: Why is that last paragraph quoted?

Comment: @BoltClock changed it to reflect the goal of the question.

Answer (score 1):

Sure here is my best interpretation of what you need in Java. Any questions and I'll alter my solution to accommodate them. This starts with an index of 0,0 for row and column.

```
int row = 0, column = 1; //it's 1 to accommodate fogr the first thing you want being a 'th' tag
List<WebElement> tableRows = driver.findElements(By.className("dataRow"));//this gets all elements on your page with a class of dataRow (which are your tr's)
for(WebElement singleRow: tableRows) //this for loop increments each of these tr's
    {
        System.out.println(singleRow.findElement(By.xpath("th[1]/a[1]")).getText()); //I'll have to use an xpath here because I don't have time to play around with other solutions but it'll work
        System.out.println("Row: " + row + ", Column: " + column);
        List<WebElement> rowTDs = singleRow.findElements(By.tagName("td"));//this gets every td in the current tr and puts it into a list
        for(WebElement singleTD: rowTDs) //this increments through that list of td's
        {
            System.out.println(singleTD.getText()); //this gives you back the text contained in that cell
            System.out.println("Row: " + row + ", Column: " + column);
            column++; //increment the column counter
        }
        column=1; //reset the column
        row++; //increment the row counter
    }
```

Edit: It seems that given that element of the request "Saykiro" has almost the right of it and you can replace in my solution tableRows = with this, there's probably a more succinct way to get the second table but this is what comes to me:

```
WebElement table1 = driver.findElemen(By.id("001Z000000vrLQe_RelatedOpportunityList_title"));
WebElement table2 = table1.findElement(By.xpath("../../../../following-sibling::table"))
List<WebElement> tableRows = table2.findElements(By.className("dataRow"));
```

Comment: thank you for the neat and clean example and it does work to an extent. If you look at the initial question the issue i need to look for table called "Opportunities" and than extract the value from the preceding table, the solution provided by you only looks at the first table  on the page and not "Opportunities" heading under the previous table. Is there way to add successor "heading = Opportunities". Thanks again for all your help.

Comment: Yeah sure I'll add the code in a few minutes. Is it just for the table following the one with heading = Opportunities?

Comment: that is right. the table following the one with heading = Opportunities

Comment: the solution with

    `List<WebElement> tableRows = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[table/tbody/tr/td/h3[text()='Opportunities']]/table[2]//*[@class='dataRow']")); `


didnt work i get the following error:

    `org.openqa.selenium.InvalidSelectorException: invalid selector: Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression //*[table/tbody/tr/td/h3[text()='Opportunities']]/table[2]//*[@class='dataRow'] because of the following error:
TypeError: Failed to execute 'createNSResolver' on 'Document': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'.`

Comment: Did that help? The sibling code should be correct, it's been a while since I've had cause to use it.

Comment: no still no success, i have added a bit more HTML for more clarification.

Answer (score 0):

For your case:

```
//*[table/tbody/tr/td/h3[text()='Opportunities']]/table[2]//td[@class=' dataCell ']
```

For C# (getting list of values in cells):

```
var values = driver.FindElements(By.XPath("//*[table/tbody/tr/td/h3[text()='Opportunities']]/table[2]//td[@class=' dataCell ']")).Select(a=>a.Text);
```

You should describe outer part of html, so we can build xpath better.

Comment: Why do so many people think xpath is the way to go? You're hardcoding and doesn't account for structure change. They'll have to redesign the test if they restructure their page. CssSelectors are infinitely better to use.

Comment: @FiHoran Could you please explain by using CssSelectors example, if xpath is not a better option, please.

Comment: @Saykiro thank you for the response and i tested the code, out the output was "0" elements found. Am i missing something here as i ran the counts for webelements, but it didnt find any matches.

Comment: @Saykiro can you please assist, as i am still not able to find any/all the elements, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hi @T-rex-the1stbreakdancer, I've fixed xpath. Tested with your markup. As I said, you should provide more html to give as a chance to build xpath better(more flexible)

Comment: @Saykiro changed the code and still no success. Count is still at "0", I have added additional HTML, for you info. Thank you again.